# Remote git commands through SSH (jenkins build step remote ssh git commands)

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

Thanks in advance for your help.

I m working on a automated build process that includes a machine running jenkins (lets call it Machine A) and a windows machine (lets call it Machine B)

On the machine B, I have a git repository working perfectly. I can run git commands on machine B for the repository with no problems while being directly on the machine (a real physical one) => SSH is set up correctly with bitbucket.

Now on the machine A, in a jenkins job, I need to run git commands in the machine B on a build step. I use a bash command to connect to B through SSH to run a bash script on B that runs git commands (an origin fetch and a pull).

It actually fails with a permission denied. On the other hand I can ssh -T in the bash script to git@bitbucket.org.

I excluded jenkins to try to understand what was going wrong so I use a machine C to connect to A with SSH then from A I connect to B through SSH usging the righ user each time and I get the same results : I can ssh -T git@bitbucket.org successfully but I get a permission denied on a git fetch origin.

Any ideas ? (I can maybe draw the setup to help you guys understand the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)

You will need to create a ssh key for the jenkins user in A and export the key to machine B.

Configure ssh key information in http.://yourjenkinsServer.domain/configure

I your job use the option "Send files or execute commands over SSH"

Comment: Dude thank you ! you made my day. I feel dumb because when I first saw it I though it was overkill and moved away but It works like a charm !